# UIButton in UITableViewCell set background color not working

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton, background-color

I have custom UITableViewCell like this :

```
@property (weak) IBOutlet UIDefaultServerButton * defaultButton;
@property (weak) IBOutlet UILabel * nameLabel;
@property (weak) IBOutlet UIRoundButton * deleteButton;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint * buttonHeight;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint * buttonWidth;

@property id <TableViewCellDelegate> delegate;

- (void) setDefaultServer: (BOOL) def;
- (void) animateLock;
- (void) animateTrash;
```

In the cellForIndex.. I add LongPress recogniser. When long press I call function animateLock.

```
- (void) animateLock
{

    [self.deleteButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lock"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    self.deleteButton.hidden = NO;

    self.deleteButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

}
```

The weird thing is that button become visible and image has been change, but backgroundColor is ignored (no matter which color I set).

Why ?

Comment: Could your nameLabel have a background colour set that is overwriting it? Otherwise, check to make sure cell.contentView background colour is clear colour too.

Comment: No in storyboard I made button blue and it stay blue, so it is not covered with anything. If I set background color to red in init method it appears red, but onely in this method it totally ignore color settings.

Comment: if u add the image for the button , then how it showing the background color ?

Comment: Image is almost all transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the image you have taken is of the same size as that of your button. Either make your image smaller or increase the area of your button.

Comment: No, it can't be it. Please see comment above. Image is 90% transparent, (like icons in tap bar - outlined all around is transparent)

Answer (score -1):

The code which you are using is perfectly fine, but the reason of background colors is not visible, is that background image is hiding the background color of UIButton. You can confirm this by commenting the line

[self.deleteButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lock"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

And then button's background will be visible.

If you can elaborate that exactly why you want to set red background of button than i will look into that.

Comment: See all commend above

Comment: Me too, and It doesn't